# Laravel orderBy datetime with timezone

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm ordering a list of events by datetime which works fine, however a problem occurs when some items have a timezone applied to them - they don't order correctly. E.g.

Event 1 - Ends 20th June 2018 at 15:00:00 (Europe/London)

Event 2 - Ends 20th June 2018 at 13:00:00 (US/Eastern)

When these are ordered by date ascending 'Event 2' shows BEFORE 'Event 1' because timezone is ignored (when in real time it's 2 hours later)

I have tried using a mutator in Laravel to convert both datetimes and timezones to timestamps:

```
 public function getDatetimeTzSecondsAttribute()
{
    $newDate = new Carbon($this->attributes['date_finish'], $this->attributes['timezone']);

    return $newDate->toTimeString();
}
```

But understand this won't work as mutators are processed after results have been fetched. I am using pagination for results - whats the best way to order this data via the query builder/eloquent if possible?

Comment: As a sidenote, this is why it's a good idea to just save everything in UTC or whatever timezone you want. As long as it's all saved in the same timezone, you can easily achieve what you want without the need for complicated comparisons and custom code.

Comment: Thanks @loek - noted - Could be an idea to crate a UTC column for all the dates perhaps. The website does show the specific date time and timezone which is the reason for splitting it

Comment: For example, yeah :) When I have this sort of requirements, I always save DateTimes in UTC and then save countries/cities/etc in a column next to them. I can then easily use the DateTimes but still have the info I need for showing correct times to the users.

Comment: Fix recommended if you don't have tons of records: alter table adding a timestamp column and seed it form your datetime+timezone column (hopefully you have a consistent timezone or you may know it from every record). Then rely on that to perform ordering.

Comment: Thanks @koalaok. The problem is that for any events that do not have a timezone set (e.g. Christmas) it is based on the visitors timezone and changes depending on where you are in the world. Not sure how this would work

Comment: Datetime it's not the correct way to save time related data in this case, expecially in cross localisation environments. You need to fix backwards your data if possible... Otherwise you definitely lost the information

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I came up with quite a simple solution after hours of brainache...

Use the MySQL 'CONVERT_TZ' function to change from timezone set to UTC:

```
->selectRaw('*, CONVERT_TZ(date_finish, timezone, \'UTC\') AS date_finish_converted ')
```

Then order by the new converted date column (if set) along with the standard date column:

```
->orderByRaw('COALESCE(date_finish_converted, date_finish), date_finish');
```

Genius! :)